# Google (Firebase) Analytics Debugger Wont Show iOS Device (Flutter Project)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have tried every solution I can find online, but I still cannot get an iOS device to show on the GA debugger view. I have added `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` to the debug scheme in XCode to my Flutter project, and tried all of the other more exotic solutions I can find online, but still nothing in the debugger console (no device even). The build is building in debug mode as specified in the console

```
2022-07-21 14:22:52 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Debug mode is on
2022-07-21 14:22:52 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Debug logging enabled
```

It even tells me how to disable it

```
2022-07-21 14:22:52 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see url)
```

It tried to log an event in debug mode also (screen view)

```
2022-07-21 14:22:52 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: screen_view (_vs), {
```

But no matter what I do, the device will not show up in the debug console, nor do the events log. The events are logged into Analytics properly, but I really want to get the debug viewer working for quicker development.

### Edit

This is the response I get when I try to log an event I specified. I am not sure if there is any useful information in there or not.

```
2022-07-21 14:37:20.755221-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][] WatchStream () headers (allowlisted): date: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 18:22:54 GMT
2022-07-21 14:37:20.755331-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][] WatchStream () response: <ListenResponse>: {
  target_change {
    resume_token: ""
    read_time {
      seconds: 1658428640
      nanos: 735306000
    }
  }
}
2022-07-21 14:37:20.755420-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction Apply remote event: 1 changes (21 bytes):
  - Put [target_global:] (21 bytes)>
2022-07-21 14:37:20.755522-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][] Committing transaction: <LevelDbTransaction NotifyLocalViewChanges: 0 changes (0 bytes):>
2022-07-21 14:37:21.655574-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Measurement timer fired
2022-07-21 14:37:21.655953-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Measurement timer canceled
2022-07-21 14:37:21.656782-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: post_shared, {
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = app;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen (_sn) = /;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = Flutter;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = ;
    shared_user_id = name;
    sharing_user_id = name;
}
2022-07-21 14:37:21.658006-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 512
2022-07-21 14:37:21.658177-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 
2022-07-21 14:37:21.661219-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1658428641661, <APMPBMeasurementBatch: 0x600000a6c590>
2022-07-21 14:37:21.662653-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2022-07-21 14:37:21.805018-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2022-07-21 14:37:21.809297-0400 Runner[] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
2022-07-21 14:37:21.905149-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
2022-07-21 14:37:21.906415-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.3162450790405273
2022-07-21 14:37:21.907766-0400 Runner[] 9.2.0 - [FirebaseAnalytics][] Measurement timer canceled
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirelly sure what exactly made debug working, but I did this:

1. Add both command arguments -FIRDebugEnabled & -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2. `FirebaseAnalytics.instance.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` in your Flutter code
3. Launch the app with XCode; for some reason when I was doing the first launch in VS Code, it didn't pick up that arguments. But then, after launching from XCode once, debug mode started working

I hope this helps

Update: -FIRDebugEnabled seems to be useless

Comment: Thanks, for some reason is just popped up after about 24 hours of waiting. I didn't change anything, but the debugger started working for me. But yes, I did have to build in XCode and no other editor (Android Studio).

Comment: yup, in my case, I only use -FIRDebugEnabled. and it will only show on DebugView only if I run it through Xcode, not from (VSCode or Android Studio). I don't know why